# VBA Export to PDF losing outlines

Tags: vba, pdf, printing, formatting, outline

When I'm using VBA to export to PDF I am losing some of the formatting.
[Image when printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQSNb.png)
[Same section exported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baE7W.png)

I am trying to use VBA to export a selected group of tabs to PDF. If I use the below code it works and the formatting is perfect but I have to use the pop up box to save the file location:

```
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=iTotal, Copies:=1, _
Preview:=False, ActivePrinter:="Microsoft Print to PDF", Collate:=True, _
PrToFileName:=sPath & sFile, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

Instead I'd like to Export to PDF using the below code as this just saves the file to the specified path without me having to interact.

```
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=sPath & sFile, Quality:=xlQualityMaximum, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

The problem is that if I use the export code the formatting isn't quite right. Some of the outlines appear to be missing so there are gaps around the edges.

Does anyone know why it formats differently using export rather than print?

Comment: I fail to see the problem when looking at the screenshot you provided. Showing both results side-by-side would help. Another question: What do you mean with "but I have to use the pop up box to save the file location"? When I run your first examle code, I only see a small pop-up for a few seconds indicating that it is printing, then it goes away without the nned of any interaction.

Comment: Thanks. The difference is the grey line down the side. It removes some of the outline when I export to PDF but doesn't when printing to PDF.

Comment: The pop up box is to tell it where to save the file and name it. In the second bit of code where I export I can state the file path in the VBA code itself without having to choose a location in the pop up window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.PrintOut` only shows the dialog, if you provide an empty string for `PrToFileName`, or if you omit the `PrToFileName` argument.

Both code demonstrations work on my machine without showing the dialog asking for pdf file name, if I provide a valid file name.

Comment: Thank you! The error with my .PrintOut was actually being caused by an error in my file path.

Comment: It doesn't explain why the Export to PDF loses formatting, but regardless it fixes my problem because I can just use .PrintOut instead. Thank you so much :)